# TextBox Not Displaying Full Text in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Currently I'm working on generating report using Microsoft Access. I have encounter problem where I'm unable to display full text in the text box. Control Source for this text box is from SQL Query.

This is example on what I'm getting right now:-

[image]

Appreciate any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

While viewing the form in Datasheet View (not Design View), double-click the edge of the column or drag to desired width. You must save the form for the formatting to stick. The width of datasheet form columns are not tied to the **Width** property in the property sheet. That's how it works in Access 2010 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have to expand the Size of the text box that is all.

Comment: I have expand the textbox, but still get same output.